# Incomplete OpenGL ES 2.0 Support

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, opengl

I'm trying to run the latest Scilab with Lubuntu 14.04, and I get an error "Mesa 10.1.3 implementation error: Incomplete OpenGL ES 2.0 support"

This is on a 10 year old Dell Dimension 8300 with all the original stuff.  The card is reported in the "Software & Updates" program "Additional Drivers" window as an NVIDEA GeForce FX 5200.

I've tried this both with the X.Org X server driver, and the NVIDIA Legacy binary driver.  The result was the same both ways.

Clues for the clueless would be much appreciated here.  Thanks.

Comment: Oops -- installing the NVIDIA driver **and then rebooting** seems to have solved the problem.

It's a good thing you don't have to be very smart to breath.

Comment: If that was the solution you should post an answer to your own question and then accept it. That way other users can easily see what worked for you :)

Comment: The first time I tried I just got a pop-up nastygram about waiting eight hours before I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Oops -- installing the NVIDIA driver **and then rebooting** seems to have solved the problem. It's a good thing you don't have to be very smart to breath.